# PCI Message Signaled Interrupts not working (edit : not working only on QEMU)

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel, osdev, pci

I tried to implement MSI Support from "osdev/PCI" page, I use APIC And IOAPIC To route interrupts, I was also working on parsing the AML And everything is good to now but the device does not generate MSI Interrupts on QEMU nor on my Primary Computer, however it does on a second Laptop (Booted in LEGACY BIOS Mode). Here is the code for MSI Enabling :

```
if(PciStatus & PCI_STATUS_CAPABILITES_LIST) {
        // Capabilites Supported
        UINT16 CapOffset = PciDeviceConfigurationRead16(Device, PCI_CAPABILITIES_PTR);
        UINT16 _caphdr = PciDeviceConfigurationRead16(Device, CapOffset);
        PCI_CAPABILITY_HEADER* CapabilityHeader = (PCI_CAPABILITY_HEADER*)&_caphdr;
        DWORD CapBuffer[0x10] = {0};
        for(;;) {
            if(CapabilityHeader->CapabilityId == PCI_CAPABILITY_ID_MSI) {

                // Copy capability buffer

                for(UINT i = 0;i<sizeof(PCI_MSI_CAPABILITY) >> 2;i++){
                    CapBuffer[i] = PciDeviceConfigurationRead32(Device, CapOffset + (i << 2));
                }
                PCI_MSI_CAPABILITY* Msi = (PCI_MSI_CAPABILITY*)CapBuffer;
                
                UINT8 MsiSystemVector = 0x32; // Just for Test


                UINT64 WriteBytes = 0;

                if(Msi->MessageControl.x64AddressCapable) {
                    PCI_MSI_CAPABILITY_64BIT* MsiX64 = (PCI_MSI_CAPABILITY_64BIT*)CapBuffer;
                    WriteBytes = sizeof(PCI_MSI_CAPABILITY_64BIT) - sizeof(PCI_CAPABILITY_HEADER);
                    MsiX64->MessageData = MsiSystemVector;
                    MsiX64->MessageAddress = (UINT64)LocalApicPhysicalAddress;
                    MsiX64->MessageControl.MsiEnable = 1;
                    MsiX64->Mask = 1;
                    MsiX64->MessageControl.MultipleMessageEnable = 0;
                _RT_SystemDebugPrint(L"PCI : MSI64 Capability MSG_CONTROL : %x, MessageAddress : %x, MSG_DATA : %x", *(UINT64*)&MsiX64->MessageControl, (UINT64)MsiX64->MessageAddress, (UINT64)MsiX64->MessageData);

                } else {
                    WriteBytes = sizeof(PCI_MSI_CAPABILITY) - sizeof(PCI_CAPABILITY_HEADER);

                    Msi->MessageData = MsiSystemVector;// | (3 << 14);
                    Msi->MessageAddress = (UINT64)LocalApicPhysicalAddress;
                    Msi->MessageControl.MsiEnable = 1;
                    Msi->Mask = 0;
                    Msi->MessageControl.MultipleMessageEnable = 0;

                _RT_SystemDebugPrint(L"PCI : MSI Capability MSG_CONTROL : %x, MessageAddress : %x, MSG_DATA : %x", *(UINT64*)&Msi->MessageControl, (UINT64)Msi->MessageAddress, (UINT64)Msi->MessageData);

                }

                
                // Some writing stuff (Everything gets written properly)
            
                UINT64 NumDwords = WriteBytes >> 2;
                UINT64 Remaining = WriteBytes & 3;
                char* tmp = (char*)Msi;
                tmp+=sizeof(PCI_CAPABILITY_HEADER);
                for(UINT i = 0;i<NumDwords;i++, tmp+=4) {
                    PciDeviceConfigurationWrite32(Device, *(UINT32*)tmp, CapOffset + (i << 2) + sizeof(PCI_CAPABILITY_HEADER));
                }
                for(UINT i = 0;i<Remaining;i++, tmp++) {
                    PciDeviceConfigurationWrite8(Device, *tmp, CapOffset + ((i + NumDwords) << 2) + sizeof(PCI_CAPABILITY_HEADER));
                }
                for(UINT i = 0;i<sizeof(PCI_MSI_CAPABILITY) >> 2;i++){
                    CapBuffer[i] = PciDeviceConfigurationRead32(Device, CapOffset + (i << 2));
                }
                
                if(Msi->MessageControl.x64AddressCapable) {
                    PCI_MSI_CAPABILITY_64BIT* MsiX64 = (PCI_MSI_CAPABILITY_64BIT*)CapBuffer;
                _RT_SystemDebugPrint(L"PCI (RESULT) : MSI64 Capability MSG_CONTROL : %x, MessageAddress : %x, MSG_DATA : %x", *(UINT64*)&MsiX64->MessageControl, (UINT64)MsiX64->MessageAddress, (UINT64)MsiX64->MessageData);

                } else {
                _RT_SystemDebugPrint(L"PCI (RESULT) : MSI Capability MSG_CONTROL : %x, MessageAddress : %x, MSG_DATA : %x", *(UINT64*)&Msi->MessageControl, (UINT64)Msi->MessageAddress, (UINT64)Msi->MessageData);

                }
            } else if(CapabilityHeader->CapabilityId == PCI_CAPABILITY_ID_MSI_X) {
                _RT_SystemDebugPrint(L"MSI-X Supported");
                while(1);
            }
            if(!CapabilityHeader->NextPointer) break;
            CapOffset = CapabilityHeader->NextPointer;
            _caphdr = PciDeviceConfigurationRead16(Device, CapOffset);
        }
    }
```

For more information : The kernel is a 64 bit (X86_64) Relocatable PE Executable made from scratch without any library and not based on any OS(unix, NT...) , I recently created a program that formats drive with FAT32 and copy files and puts My bootsector & bootmanager on it. The kernel runs in APIC ACPI Mode, it has a multiprocessor preemptive priority schedulling mechanism, one TSS & GDT Per processor. I am currently working on EHCI & AHCI Drivers and I needed interrupts so I was parsing the ACPI AML ( not finished), and now I'm trying MSI before I parse that AML.

Comment: Can you give some further contextual information. Is this code snippet found in a UEFI app? Is it a kernel elf file booted with UEFI? What is the architecture? How do you compile the whole thing? Etc.. It seems like you are developing a full kernel from scratch and a lot of things can go wrong. It can actually be something very unrelated. Since you say that it works with a legacy BIOS than it might be related to the way you set up your UEFI kernel. You don't provide much info so it is hard to tell.

Comment: Yeah I see, I had not alot of time and I started creating this kernel (and the O.S) a year ago in hope to make it work on modern devices (which maked things harder) it is a separate micro-kernel that is hybrid bootable UEFI & LEGACY BIOS and it is a pe64+ on the architecture x86_64 structures are all packed, I can post the header file and definitions if u want. The kernel supports preemtive priority mutitasking (feedback queue), relocatable driver loading , memory management, pci & smbios, APIC / IOAPIC Only Mode and some bunch of stuff. ACPI Compatible currently working on AML.

Comment: Additionnally, I just completed LEGACY BIOS Support **Yesterday**, (BootLoader and FAT32 File system) which works fine on windows. I started creating the kernel from scratch without any library in a UEFI Environnement.

Comment: Here it is @user123

Comment: @user123 **Update :** Message Signaled Interrupts are signaled on my primary computer, my second (old) laptop, and on Virtual Box but they doesn't work on QEMU

Comment: You seem to know more than I do so I cannot be of big help. For QEMU, use gdb and debug the VM. That should help finding the culprit.

Comment: I heard that a device can support MSI But the host PCI Configuration may not support it so it doesn't work, I have no idea how to get pci version but I'll try supporting this feature by emulating on VBox. @user123

Comment: On QEMU, you need to use ```-M q35```. This is an option to enable the newer q35 chipset. Don't do the mistake of emulating with VBox. That'll be much worse. QEMU uses the emulation features of xHCI and you can easily have an AHCI on QEMU. You just need to tell QEMU that you want to add those devices with ```-device qemu-xhci``` and ```-device ahci```. By the way, I did use MSI-X (newer version of MSI) in the past when writing an xHCI driver in a kernel written from scratch. QEMU does support MSI/MSI-X.

Comment: Thanks, I"ll try enabling XHCI (which is my target driver after EHCI) , however I'm already using -machine q35

Comment: @user123 It doesn't work, maybe it's a problem with my APIC Configuration, I'll also try MSI-X (but I need to start an XHCI Driver) to see if it is a problem in my kernel. How do you setup the APIC. For me I "Hardware enable it" by writing it's address to IA32_APIC_BASE_MSR, then I setup Spurious & LVT Interrupts & set logical_destination to 0 & destination_format to (0xF << 28) then I clear task priority and Setup the APIC_TIMER.  I can temporarily turn the kernel public on github for you.

Comment: @user123 look, MSI Was already working I just needed to trigger an error in the AHCI to make it signal an interrupt loolllll, I had to enable interrupt on other things. However sorry very much cause I waisted your time, and thank you so much for your time here is a +1

Comment: No problem, happy that it worked out.